# jsoup specifically parsing href

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup, href

Right now im calling all the links off a page on reddit and printing it out, but what can I add to my loop to only keep the links that begin with http://www.reddit.com/r/askcience/ ?

```
    Document doc; 
    try {


        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/search?q=flair%3A%27Psych%27&sort=top&restrict_sr=on").get();


        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link : links) {

            System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: read the doc for String.startsWith ?

Comment: or, read the doc for css selector.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you gotta [read the docs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html).

> `[attr^=valPrefix] elements with an attribute named "attr", and value starting with "valPrefix"`

Otherwise, you can suck in all of the links and use a regular expression or `startsWith()` on the strings

Comment: I think you have to include the `http://` part, too, if that's in the source code (absolute reference versus relative reference).